# gedit – Location on disk of profiles' settings

Tags: 18.04, configuration, gedit, settings

I created two new profiles in Text Editor (gedit) with custom colors. I'd like to backup those settings.

There is nothing related to profiles, for example, in `~/.config/gedit/` or `~/.local/share/gedit/`.

Where does gedit save the profile settings?

Comment: I new about custom tags like "TODO" but not this, I'll have to research this more. Out of curiosity does it work for `sudo` as well?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Actually what I really wanted to know was how to backup my custom profiles in `gnome-terminal` but for some reason I was looking for the settings for `gedit` (oops). I only realized my mistake later on and since I actually got an answer to the (wrong) question I made I thought it'd be polite to accept it. (I already found what I wanted, BTW.) So I don't know the answer to your question. :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Color Schemes can be placed in the following locations:

```bsh
# global
/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles
# for user
~/.local/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles
```

or

```bsh
# global
/usr/share/gedit/styles
# for user
~/.local/share/gedit/styles
```

If the directories do not exist, you can simply create them.